# How to setup a USB wlan connection and wifi hospot connection on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi and WiFi dongle.. I do WiFi wlan connection and hotspot WiFi connection.. at a time working any one of this..is it possible both connection will work at a time in raspberry pi .. can any one help

Comment: Do you mean to ask if your wifi dongle can be connected to two networks at the same time?

Comment: S @JonathanV 1. local wifi connection 2.broadcast  hotspot